# Will this call GetEnumerator() More than Once?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, enumeration

In our code base, we have a data access layer that provides methods similar to:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos()
{
    var collection = new Collection<Foo>();

    // ...call db

    while (read results)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
    }

    return collection;
}
```

So while the method signature return an IEnumerable, under the hood, it created a Collection (which is already enumerated). Will consumers of this method that are expecting an IEnumerable actually call GetEnumerator(), or will they actually, albeit unknowingly, be using a Collection?

```
IEnumerable<Foo> myFoos = GetFoos();

// will .Any() cause enumeration even though it's a Collection under the hood?
if (myFoos != null && myFoos.Any())
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will always call `GetEnumerator()`.

We can verify this by inspecting [the implementation of `Any()` on ReferenceSource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0):

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (e.MoveNext()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you are concerned about performance, but still want to restrict the ability of consumers to change the collection, you could consider returning [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh881542%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is effectively just an `IEnumerable<T>` along with a `Count` property. Then the consumer can check the `Count` property, but otherwise cannot do anything other than to enumerate it. (Except if they start doing nasty things like casting it to the original collection type...)

Comment: But note that it only looks to see if it do `MoveNext` once since that is sufficient to establish that the collection has *any* items. So while it calls `GetEnumerator` it *does not* iterate through the whole collection.

Comment: Indeed - so it is very efficient for a collection.

Comment: Yes, compare to [Count()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b) for example. So `Count() > 0` has to iterate the whole collection, although it does check if the source is `ICollection` and uses the `Count` property instead in that case.

Comment: Well, I say "very efficient".. but in reality it still has to create an object rather than just returning `list.Count > 0` for example.

Comment: (to your latest comment) Yes. Note that if `source` is a `List<>`, then the `public` method `GetEnumerator` returns a mutable `struct` type. So when we use `foreach (var x in somethingOfCompileTimeTypeList)` the enumerator consists of only a field (holding current index) which is on the stack. But with `Any`, we cannot call the `public` `GetEnumerator`, we get instead the explicit interface implementation, and it returns that mutable struct __in a box__. So we get boxing, and the garbage collector must collect that box with the enumerator at some time.

Comment: OK, I inspected that struct, `List<>.Enumerator`, on ReferenceSource, and it has four fields (not one as I said). These are: `private List<T> list; 
private int index; 
private int version; 
private T current;` So a reference back to the `List<>` the enumerator belongs to. An `index` for the current position. A `version` to keep track of whether the `List<>` has been changed by someone else while we iterate. And a `current` of type `T` (where `T` is defined by the containing class). So that is one object reference, two `int32`, and one `T` (whose size depends on what `T` is).

Comment: I'm still not clear on this. If I explicitly create a `List<T>`, then call methods like `Any` or `Count`, it's going to enumerate on each of those method calls? I thought once you have a `List`, then it doesn't need to enumerate subsequent method calls.

Comment: @Didaxis EVERY time you call `Any()` it will execute the code that I posted. So it will call `GetEnumerator()` each time. It's very fast, though.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Right, so returning `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` would be an optimisation only if `.Count` was called a lot?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid enumeration for a collection in this case, you could do the follwoing:

```
ICollection col = myFoos as ICollection;
bool hasItems = false;
if (col != null && col.Count > 0)
{
   hasItems = true;
}
else
{
   hasItems = (myFoos != null && myFoos.Any());
}
```

But this probably has more overhead than just calling `.Any()` instead - whatever savings you get from checking `.Count` are likely offset by the cost of checking if `myFoos` is an `ICollection` and loading it up.  The only advantage to doing it this way is if you wanted to operate on the object as if it were an `ICollection` for some other reason.  Your other option would be to just have your `GetFoos` function return an `ICollection` to begin with...